# Website Stuck in Left Alignment on iPad

Tags: css, mobile-safari

This Wordpress site is normally center aligned in browsers, except for Safari on iPad. On the iPad, the site is weirdly left justified (no whitespace on the left).

I've tested it other (non iPad) browsers and can't repeat the issue.

iPad Screenshot: [image]

URL: http://rainleader.com

I'm lost as to what could be causing this. Almost everything has a CSS width value...

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You have relatively positioned menu shifted from the left.

Comment: That was it! Why do layouts like this break with relatively positoned menus? `left: 200px; top: -5em;` breaks the layout but `width: 36em; margin: 0 auto; top: -5em;` is fine. I thought using margin to center was a bad practice.

Comment: Quiet the opposite: it's a standard practice. And while you can't accept this "answer" of mine, I would appreciate if you'll go to my profile and vote for my other answers that you'll find worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have this:

```
body { font-size: 13px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #111; background-image: url('http://cdn.rainleader.com/assets/bg_top_outer.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-x; text-align:center; }
#container { width: 900px; margin-top: 25px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

change to this

```
body { [add this] text-align:center }
[change to this] #container { width: 900px; margin-top: 25px; margin: 0 auto; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  text-align:left; }
```

this is how I always center things and it always works.

1) Align center in body (You didn't do this)

2) margin 0 auto in container (You only had auto and no 0)

3) specify width in container

4) align left in container to undo center from body